# Windows 8 Metro RSA Encryption: AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider ImportPublicKey Fails

Tags: wcf, microsoft-metro, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am attempting to pass some encrypted data between a Win 8 Metro app and a RESTful WCF service. Initially the Metro app requests a public key and the WCF service returns it as a raw Stream as to avoid any pesky formatting issues. The Base 64 encoded public key is decoded in the metro app into a byte array. Here is where the problem occurs. When I attempted to call AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.ImportPublicKey I get the error "ASN1 bad tag value met".

I am using RSA PKCS1 for the encryption. Here is the relevant code:

**WCF Service**

```
     string keyName = "This is passed in via a parameter";
     var key = !CngKey.Exists(keyName) ? CngKey.Create(CngAlgorithm2.Rsa, keyName) : CngKey.Open(keyName);

     // Create the RSA container to get keys and then dispose
     using (var rsaCng = new RSACng(key) { EncryptionPaddingMode = AsymmetricPaddingMode.Pkcs1, KeySize = 2048 })
     {
        byte[] publicBlob = rsaCng.Key.Export(CngKeyBlobFormat.GenericPublicBlob);
        publicKey = Convert.ToBase64String(publicBlob);
     }
```

**Metro App**

```
  public static string Encrypt(IBuffer dataBuffer, string publicKeyString)
  {
     var asymmAlg = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);
     // The next line fails with ASN1 bad tag value met
     var publicKey = asymmAlg.ImportPublicKey(CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(publicKeyString), CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Pkcs1RsaPublicKey);

     var encryptedData = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(publicKey, dataBuffer, null);
     return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(encryptedData);
  }
```

**EDIT 1: More information below**

Exporting the public key from a 2048bit key pair from the WCF service yields a 283 bit length key blob, while exporting the same type of public key from the Metro app is only 270 bits. When I import the Metro generated public key it succeeds. Any idea why the WCF service has 13 extra bits on its public key? I think those extra 13 bits are causing the failure.

Here is the Metro code that yields the shorter public key blob:

```
var provider = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);
CryptographicKey standardKeyPair = provider.CreateKeyPair(2048);
byte[] standardKey = standardKeyPair.ExportPublicKey(CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Pkcs1RsaPublicKey).ToArray();
```

Comment: It might be worth asking here instead : http://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Quite late, but maybe it will help you or saves someone's time...

Change the type of blob type during import. It's really wierd, but I had success with it, after experimenting.

Your code in WCF may stay as it is.

Change just the Metro code:

```
public static string Encrypt(IBuffer dataBuffer, string publicKeyString)
{
    var asymmAlg = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);
    // The next line fails with ASN1 bad tag value met
    var publicKey = asymmAlg.ImportPublicKey(CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(publicKeyString), CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.BCryptPublicKey);

    var encryptedData = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(publicKey, dataBuffer, null);
    return CryptographicBuffer.EncodeToBase64String(encryptedData);
}
```

So the only change here is the `BCryptPublicKey` during the importing. Then it works. But do not ask me why :-).