# Importing a RSA PKCS1 public key from .Net 4.5 into Winrt

Tags: c#, security, windows-runtime, cryptography

I have a requirement to use a public RSA key that a winrt app retrieves from a service.

```
var decodedKey = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(serverKey.Value);
```

So the service delivers my app a base 64 encoded string which is a public rsa key.  The key is created using RSA PKCS1 padding.

Reference this post from awhile back:
[Windows 8 Metro RSA Encryption: AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider ImportPublicKey Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461649/windows-8-metro-rsa-encryption-asymmetrickeyalgorithmprovider-importpublickey-f)

That is exactly what I am trying to do.  While it is true that changing the blob type to something other than Pkcs1 like BCryptPublicKey or Capi1PublicKey will allow the server public key to be imported this is only a hack and not a solution.

```
        var provider = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithmNames.RsaPkcs1);
        var decodedKey = CryptographicBuffer.DecodeFromBase64String(serverKey.Value);           
        var publicKey = provider.ImportPublicKey(decodedKey, CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType.Capi1PublicKey);
```

When I get to the next step which looks like:

```
var encryptedBuffer = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(publicKey, data, null);
```

Where data is an IBuffer.  I received another exception almost certainly due to the fact that the public key was imported as a format that it was not in (Pkcs1 versus Capi1/BCrypt). The exception is an ArgumentException with message "Value does not fall within the expected range.".  I did try giving this method some arbirtraru iv buffer instead of null, and that had no effect.

How do you  get a .Net 4.5 generated ket to interop with WinRt?

Comment: PKCS#1 padding is used for key encryption, not key generation. Is that a typo?

Comment: Not a typo... I am trying to figure this all out for my first time.  So pkcs1 means the generated key is encrypted?  The would explain my trouble importing it in the app.  How to I teach the app to decrypt the public key before importing it?

Comment: PKCS#1 is a standard that describes RSA signature generation and verification, encryption and decryption. These RSA modes require padding to be used, and these padding modes are described as well. Padding however is not used during key pair generation. You may want to download and read the standard, it is quite comprehensible.